# How to install both versions of PyMC?

Tags: pymc

I am wanting to install BOTH versions of PyMC (i.e 2.3.4 and 3.0). Can someone advise what is the best way to do that?

(I currently used Anaconda to install PyMC, but happy to do something different.)
Then how do I import the version I want into Python?

Answer (score 1):

I have a fork of PyMC3 where the namespace is changed to pymc3: https://github.com/aflaxman/pymc .

You should be able to install it with `python setup.py install`, and then use it with `import pymc3 as pm`.

It is not up-to-date, however, so patches accepted...

Answer (score 1):

My "kludge" is to install pymc in python2.7 and pymc3 in python3.  It sounds dodgy but it actually works for me quite well in practice.